# on Scroll navigation bar is overlaped by caret down Icon

Tags: html, jquery, css

On selecting the list item `caret` symbol is toggled to `caret-down` facing downwards and
When I scroll the list the caret-down Icon is being overlapping the navigation bar.

caret up is working good but why the caret down alone is overlapping?

Please help me in resolving

```js
$('.log-info li').prepend($('<span>&nbsp;</span>').addClass('caret'))
$(document).on('click', '.log-info li', function(event) {
          let getdash1 = document.querySelectorAll('.log-info') 
          getdash1.forEach(function(o) {
            if($(o).hasClass("log-select")){
              $(o).removeClass("log-select")
            }
          })
          $(this).addClass("log-select");
        })
 $('.caret,.log-info li').on('click', function(e) {

   $('.caret,.log-info li').toggleClass('caret-down');
              
        })
```

```css
.nav-tabs{
  position: fixed;
}
.log-pagerow
{
justify-content: center;
height: 80%;
}
.Log-container
{
height: 100%;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: white;
overflow:scroll;
position: relative;
box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
 #log-menu{
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .whole-log-container
{
  margin-top: 3%;
  height: 80%;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  }
  .caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  }
  
  .caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: #8F9779;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  }
  .caret-down::before {
    display: inline-block;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
  }
  .log-select{
    color: white;
    background-color: #28be9a;
    padding: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid whole-log-container">
<div class="row log-pagerow">
  <div class="col-sm-8 Log-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#summary-log" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="summary-log">
        <ul class="log-info" id="log-menu">
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
         <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change this line $('.caret,.log-info li').toggleClass('caret-down'); into $(this).toggleClass('caret-down'); Rest is good in your code.

Comment: add z-index:99 to nav-tabs class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add z-index to `nav-tabs`

```
.nav-tabs{
  z-index:9;
}
```

```js
$('.log-info li').prepend($('<span>&nbsp;</span>').addClass('caret'))
$(document).on('click', '.log-info li', function(event) {
          let getdash1 = document.querySelectorAll('.log-info') 
          getdash1.forEach(function(o) {
            if($(o).hasClass("log-select")){
              $(o).removeClass("log-select")
            }
          })
          $(this).addClass("log-select");
        })
 $('.caret,.log-info li').on('click', function(e) {

   $('.caret,.log-info li').toggleClass('caret-down');
              
        })
```

```css
.nav-tabs{
  position: fixed;
  z-index:99;
}
.log-pagerow
{
justify-content: center;
height: 80%;
}
.Log-container
{
height: 100%;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: white;
overflow:scroll;
position: relative;
box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
 #log-menu{
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .whole-log-container
{
  margin-top: 3%;
  height: 80%;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  }
  .caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  }
  
  .caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: #8F9779;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  }
  .caret-down::before {
    display: inline-block;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(90deg);  
  }
  .log-select{
    color: white;
    background-color: #28be9a;
    padding: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid whole-log-container">
<div class="row log-pagerow">
  <div class="col-sm-8 Log-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#summary-log" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="summary-log">
        <ul class="log-info" id="log-menu">
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
         <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        <li>data</li>
        </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```